# Target all elements in a list excepted clicked

Tags: javascript, each

I've been playing around with jQuery for ages but am finally trying to learn clean Vanilla JS.

I have a list of elements:

```
    <div id="seriesList" class="seriesList rollable">

            <div class="seriesLink" series="7">
                <a href="#carrow-road"><h3 class="name">Carrow Road</h3><p class="location">Norwich</p></a>
            </div>

            <div class="seriesLink" series="6">
                <a href="#white-lane"><h3 class="name">White Heart Lane</h3><p class="location">London</p></a>
            </div>

            <div class="seriesLink" series="5">
                <a href="#parc-des-princes"><h3 class="name">Parc des Princes</h3><p class="location">Paris</p></a>
            </div>
</div
```

I'm toggling a series of GSAP animation after clicking one of the .seriesLink. The first one i'm trying to achieve is making every elements exept the one clicked disapear.
i.e: I click on #carrow-road — #white-lane and #parc-des-princes would disapear.

I have this:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".seriesLink").forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {

// ForEach.Not ?

    document.getElementById("seriesList").classList.toggle("rollable");
    document.getElementById("home").classList.add("scrollable");
    document.getElementById("rightPanel").classList.remove("scrollable");
    tlOpenSeries.play();
  })
})
```

The "class" system in Javascript is getting me lost, as I don't seem to be able to target my elements successfully.

I can't find a way to "reproduce" the each.not jquery provides. Any idea? Shall I add a class first to the clicked element and **then** target all elements without this "active" class? Is there a shortcut?

Many thanks

Comment: item.addEventListener('click', event => anonymous arrow function makes it difficult to know what element is clicked on. No 'this'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To accomplish that in vanilla JS you have to loop through the elements and check if the current element is not the clicked element.

**Demo:**

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".seriesLink");
divs.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {

    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
      if(event.currentTarget != divs[i]){ // check here
        divs[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    
    //.......
    //.......
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="seriesList" class="seriesList rollable">
  <div class="seriesLink" series="7">
    <a href="#carrow-road"><h3 class="name">Carrow Road</h3><p class="location">Norwich</p></a>
  </div>

  <div class="seriesLink" series="6">
    <a href="#white-lane"><h3 class="name">White Heart Lane</h3><p class="location">London</p></a>
  </div>

  <div class="seriesLink" series="5">
    <a href="#parc-des-princes"><h3 class="name">Parc des Princes</h3><p class="location">Paris</p></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `filter`:

```
const seriesLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".seriesLink");

seriesLinks.forEach(item => {
   item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    
      seriesLinks
        .filter(i => i != item)
        .forEach(i => // your logic... //);

//... rest of your code ... //
   })
})
```

but anymay i think that a good practice is to split the code to simple little functions, for example `hideAllExceptCurrent (allElemArray, currentElem)`, `hideAllToggleCurrent (allElemArray, currentElem)`

Comment: Why is this better to set seriesLink as a const beforehand? Performance-wise or just to make the reading easier?

Comment: make the reading easier. the performance lack is very very negligible here

Comment: I'd share certain efficiency concerns regarding the above solution: it is more safe and easier to maintain *single* event listener on wrapping element than listening per each child node; `.querySelectorAll()` is a great tool *for advanced queries*, `.getElementsByClassName()` in this particular scenario would perform better; above code loops ***unnecessarily*** twice (with `.filter()` and `.forEach()`) through all the links unnecessarily, single pass with `.forEach()` applying necessary logic conditionally, seems to be more reasonable.